# My dog killed a bunny in my yard

Tags: dogs, behavior

I adopted a lab from the local shelter about a week ago, he is about 1 year old. I have a cat at home the dog is playful by his demeanor with his interaction with my cat. I have adopted this dog for a week and just watching him closely with my cat due to his playful nature.  I let him outside my yard and my neighbor's bunny got in and my dog killed it. Should I be concerned for my cat and will this trigger some sort of change in his behavior? Should I consider returning him to the shelter?

Comment: If you want a dog that probably won't kill rabbits ,try a dog smaller than the rabbits. Although a cat can kill a rabbit that is as large as the cat.

Comment: It's impossible to know the thoughts of a dog or to predict his behavior correctly all the time. An indicator could be **how** the bunny was killed. Was it bitten at the throat or head? Was it's neck broken? Did it look like it just dropped dead without any obvious injury? And did your dog bark or snarl while doing it?

Comment: It's in their nature to hunt. If he hasn't harmed the cat yet then I think you should be okay, but keep watch just in case as its only been a week.

Comment: There's no telling what will happen. Do you really want to risk your cat's life like this? Cats are not that much bigger than rabbits. If the cat triggers the dog's prey drive, it's over. Don't risk it.